# Change data source for SQL Server Reports automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, database-connection

We have an ASP .NET MVC  web application that links to some SQL Server Reporting Services reports.  Our web application uses one database for the morning (let's call this the "AM database") and a different database for the afternoon/night ("PM database").

We have a SQL Server Agent job set up that switches the connection string for the web application from the AM database to the PM database (or vice-versa) on a schedule.  It works by copying/replacing the MVC application's `Web.config` file with the appropriate AM/PM version.  This works as intended.

However, the reports will remain pointed to whichever database they were using previously, unless the data source is manually changed through SSRS.  These reports need to be updated to point to the same database as the MVC web app.

How can I automate this process (preferably through SQL Server Agent)?  We need the reports to change their database connection on a regular interval.

Comment: Creating a !DatabaseServerName and !DatabaseName as parameters to each report would allow your mvc app to feed in the correct database. I use this method to point to multiple databases. As for automation...you might look into the ssrs database for connection info but I think that info is pent up in the rdl and datsource files and have never tried to extract it.

Comment: Have any links or info on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This  works for embedded connections I am not sure about shared data source references. Just add two parameters to your report for database name and database server name. You could also use codes or mask the names if you prefer not so send this info over the wire.

In your embedded data set add the following as your connectionstring

```
expression:="Data Source="+Parameters!DatabaseServerName.Value+";Initial Catalog="&Parameters!DatabaseName.Value
```

Next, add a defined user for your credentials then all you need to do is pass in the two params for each report from your application.

NOTE: You need to add your defaults when designing to a server that is accessible.

Comment: I did this, and when I pass the parameters through the URL, it always reverts to the default parameters instead.

Comment: Eh, Set the hidden flag on them and set to allow null and allow blank.